# Drawing to a brush

Tags: c#, wpf

I have made a control which inherits TextBox, and I'm trying to give a notebook grid:

[image: Notebook page]

I already have the code that will specify where to draw the lines including all of the grids features, but I'm not sure what to draw it to.
I've Googled a lot and searched for a brush that will let me have the same interface as a DrawingContext (so I could call drawingContext.DrawLine() etc.), or something familiar, but I couldn't find any!

**So how can I achieve to get my grid background?**

*P.S I can't create a static bmp file and load it, because the grid color and spacing would most certainly change*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using [`DrawingVisual`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.drawingvisual.aspx) to get your [`DrawingContext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.drawingcontext.aspx) then create a [`VisualBrush`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.drawingvisual.aspx) to assign to your `Background`. Something like this.

```
DrawingVisual dv = new DrawingVisual();
DrawingContext dc = dv.RenderOpen();

dc.DrawLine( new Pen(Brushes.Red,5),new Point(0,0),new Point(50,50));
dc.Close();

VisualBrush vb = new VisualBrush(dv);
textBox1.Background = vb;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can intercept the `Paint` event for your control. You get a `PaintEventArgs` argument, which includes a `ClipRectangle` and a `Graphics` object.

Check out [Control.Paint Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.paint%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

Once you have your `Graphics` object, you can call `DrawLine` and `FillRectangle` on it directly.

Comment: Thanks, but my program uses WPF, but WinForms.

Comment: It's my understanding that you still get a paint event in your controls. I may be wrong, though.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking to make a custom-drawn control. You'll want to override the OnPaint method of your control class and draw the background in that method. Here's an example on how to do it: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b818z6z6(v=vs.90).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b818z6z6%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

To draw your background, grab the drawing context and draw your background after first calling the base OnPaint method:

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pe)
{
   // Call the OnPaint method of the base class.
   base.OnPaint(pe);

   // Declare and instantiate a new pen.
   System.Drawing.Pen myPen = new System.Drawing.Pen(Color.Aqua);

   // Draw an aqua rectangle in the rectangle represented by the control.
   pe.Graphics.DrawRectangle(myPen, new Rectangle(this.Location, this.Size));
}
```

**EDIT:** 
Since you're using WPF, you can take a look here to see a full example on custom designs: [WPF .NET 3.5 Drawing Customized Controls and Custom UI Elements](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22003/WPF-and-NET-3-5-Drawing-Customized-Controls-and-Cu)